# Check whether two graph intersected?

Tags: python, graph, intersection

I want to make a call whenever the two graphs get intersected
Here's [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fegtl.png)

here's the data https://jpn698dhc9.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/v2/historical?symbol=%22degods%22

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two time series as equally-indexed `pd.Series` objects, you can simply subtract them, determine the signs of the differences (which tells you which is higher), determine the differences of these signs over time (which tells you whether or not the order of the two has changed) and look at whenever those sign differences are non-zero (which tells you that there was a change in the order, i.e. an intersection of the graph). The following code computes the indices of all timesteps between whose and their respective predecessors there were intersections:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.Series([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0])
s2 = pd.Series([0.0, 1.3, 2.6, 3.9, 5.2, 6.5])
diffs = np.sign(s1 - s2).diff()[1:]
indices = diffs[diffs.ne(0)].index.values
```